# Unable to uninstall Onedrive For Business

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Onedrive For Business always appears in the tray bar on a Windows 10 pc.
It's already uninstalled in Control Panel and disabled at startup.
Syncing has been paused.

However it keeps reappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive can be uninstalled from some versions of Windows 10:

1. Select the **Start** button, type ***Programs*** in the search box, and then select **Add or remove programs** in the list of results.
2. Under **Apps & features**, find and select **Microsoft OneDrive**, and then select **Uninstall**.

As OneDrive is built in to some versions of Windows and can't be uninstalled. As a workaround, you can hide it. Reference “**Turn off or uninstall OneDrive**” for detail steps:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-off-or-uninstall-OneDrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0

Comment: The link works, it's hidden now. The only thing still remaining is Onedrive in File Explorer. I now found another way of hiding it. https://www.howtogeek.com/225973/how-to-disable-onedrive-and-remove-it-from-file-explorer-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive for Business seems to be part of Office, not a separate application. To uninstall it:

(**Note:** The exact locations and wording may vary depending which version of Windows and Office you have installed)

1. Go to *Settings* > *System* > *Apps & features*
2. Click *Microsoft Office* > *Modify*
3. *Add or Remove Features* > *Continue*
4. From the list, click *Microsoft OneDrive for Business* > *Not Available* > *Continue*

Answer (score -1):

Use
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to disable it completely.

Type "onedrive" in the Filter field in the Everything tab, and uncheck all entries.